# FilenameUtils in grails 3?

Tags: grails

I'm using **Grails 3** and I **dont't find FilenameUtils** in Grails 3.

(I want to upgrade my grails 2 plugin to grails 3)

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils
FilenameUtils.concat(path,it)
```

**Should** I **recopy and adapt** all the class?

or somebody find the repositoring ?

And when I put the depencies :

```
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6' //last released version
```

I don't have commons.io right here.

[image: See I don't have IO]

Solved by this =>

[image]

Comment: Did you mean that autocomplete is not working? Looks like you only need to resfresh gradle dependencies in your IDE

Comment: yes but if I write the full package that works. I just had to clic on the red bulb and use the first option who says : put in the classpath or gradle commons-io:2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FilenameUtils` isn't part of grails 3 core framework. But sometimes when you install 3rd-party plugins, you get those classes from those plugins. But you should consider adding `apache.commons.io` in your grails 3 `build.gradle` dependencies.

```
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6' //last released version
```

Comment: Are you sure? Because I just checked javadoc for 2.6. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html. It's there. If you can share your build.gradle

Comment: You shouldn't post part of the problem as an answer. I'll suggest editing the original question.

Comment: If you are using idea, please open the gradle window from right side (usually) and refresh, you need this if you change your gradle dependency and don't have auto import enabled. or try grails clean / gradle clean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163881/discussion-between-mamun-sardar-and-eliot-praz).